# Android Development real Virtual machine

Tags: android

Is there any way that i use my phone as virtual device in Android Development Kit on Windows?
I turn on USB debugging but in device list nothing happens its blank.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of phone are you trying to use?

Comment: Also make sure you are not plugged into a USB 3.0 slot. It only works in USB 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install your device driver on windows

Turn on USB debugging mode on your Device

Then connect to Pc

Go to ADT  >  Go to DDMS

Restart ADB > youll see your device